# How to process large file in minimum time (c++, openmp, input file : FASTQ/FASTA)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, bioinformatics

I have a multi-threaded application(OpenMP), in which we are reading a very large file of size ( 10GB - 350GB) containing genomic reads(strings).
Due to limited RAM (8 GB), we are trying to process this big input file in chunks, where we are pushing some x number of strings into a vector and processing it using multiple threads. This process repeats till all strings in the input file get completely processed. But this approach is very slow.
We even tested the code by varying the size of the array (1000000 strings), but it required more time than the array of size 1000
How can I optimize it in terms of time?

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
#include <zlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kseq.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
    gzFile fp;
    kseq_t *seq;
    int l;
    int it;
    int read_count=0;
    fp = gzopen("dm.fastq", "r");
    seq = kseq_init(fp);
    vector <string> array;       
 while ((l = kseq_read(seq)) >= 0) 
    {
            if (read_count <= 999) 
        {
                array.push_back(seq->seq.s);
                read_count++;
        }
            if (read_count == 1000) 
        {
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(12) schedule(static) private(it) shared(array)
                for (it = 0; it < array.size(); ++it) 
            {
                string line = array[it];
                            int size_s = line.size();
                            char _buf[size_s + 1];
                            strcpy(_buf, line.c_str());
            }
        array.clear();    
        read_count=0;
        }
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(12) schedule(static) private(it) shared(array)
        for (it = 0; it < array.size(); ++it) 
            {
                            string line = array[it];
                            int size_s = line.size();
                            char _buf[size_s + 1];
                            strcpy(_buf, line.c_str());
            }
    
    kseq_destroy(seq);gzclose(fp);return 0;
}//main close
```

Comment: Is your program CPU-bound or I/O bound?  If it's CPU-bound, you may be able to improve its performance by reducing the frequency with which your program allocates or frees heap-allocations.  (For example, if you know in advance the maximum number of items you will put into your vector, you can pre-`reserve()` that many slots in the vector to avoid unnecessary reallocations -- and if each `string` is likely to be the same size (or nearly the same size) as all the others, then you can avoid using the `string` class entirely, and use a fixed-size data-type instead.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank for your comments. The Implementation is i/O bound.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that is just reading (without processing) from a standard spinning HDD a 100Gb file should take about 17 minutes.

Second, about your code - it has openmp in places where this does not matter and has no-op operations (`strcpy(_buf` one). This **for** loop does not take that much CPU to parallelize it. Probably, this is just an example, but it does matter.

And for last, most(like 90%) of CPU is eaten in library(**kseq_read**) and **gzopen** (and seems your 100Gb files is compressed).

Comment: Could you please suggest a library for fast reading of FASTA and FASTQ file (file size: 197 GB)
OR the shall we write custom code for reading a FASTQ file is ok?